# Updating all sub-branches with changes of the parent branch

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have three branches: a master branch with two sub-branches A and B.

If I just made some changes in branch A, how can I update those changes in both the master branch and branch B? Does git allow us to do this all at once with just a merge into the master branch (and subsequently trickle down to branch B), or do I have to merge the changes into the master branch and then manually merge the changes in the updated master branch into branch B?

Would love some advice!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `master` has two branches `A` and `B` extant, the typical way a change in A would make its way into `B` would be via merging or rebasing.  Assuming merging:

```
# from master
git merge A
git checkout B
git merge master
```

At this point, whatever change happened in `A` would also now be present in the parent branch `master` as well as the other feature branch `B`.